# Laravel api versioning - How to handle shared functions among versions?

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5 and building web service for an application which needs api versioning. This is the folder structure I found so far in different web resources

```
/app
  /controllers
    /Api
      /v1
        /UserController.php
      /v2
        /UserController.php
```

The problem is there are many functions in the `UserController` that most likely will be unchanged among versions or any change might be applied to every version. For example there is an `logout` function which sends a message to user after logout. If I copy this function in every `UserController`, then any minor change, say changing the message or anything like that, makes me to change every `UserController` in different versions. As a result I decided to create a `BaseUserController` and insert the shared functions in there and every `Usercontroller` should inherit this. I mean this

```
/app
  /controllers
    /Api
      /BaseUserController.php extends Controller.php
      /v1
        /UserController.php extends BaseUserController.php
      /v2
        /UserController.php extends BaseUserController.php
```

so if any version needs to implement its own `logout`, simply it overrides its parent function or for any global change, I change the function in the parent.

I would like to ask you, is this a good strategy to implement api versioning? and what is the problem with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, what you have done is one of the many solutions to this problem.
What I personally prefer is to use a service layer, which contains most of the common logic, which can be used from different points in the application.

```
/app
 /services
  /UserService.php
```

Again this is personal preference and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

As @GreedChikara said its kind of personal choice... My structure looks like below..

```
/app
  /controllers
    /Api
      /UserController.php
      /v2/
        /UserControllerV2.php
```

And what I do to reduce duplication - always extend the previous version  and override the methods that need to behave differently from previous version -

```
class UserControllerV2 extends UserController {


    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     */
    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
    }

    ##Overridden methods.....
}
```